# Armstrong number using prompt sync

Tags: javascript

```
var num = require("prompt-sync")()("message")
const armstrongNumber = (num) => {

  const toArray = num.toString().split('').map(Number);

  const newNum = toArray.map(a => {return a**3}).reduce((a, b) => a + b); //Here we need to change the expontenial power accordingly to sum of own digits 

  if(newNum == num){
      console.log('This is an armstrong number');
  }else{
      console.log('This is not an armstrong number');

  }
}
armstrongNumber(num)
```

how to do if I use loop statements in the function?
I used while loop in the function, but then in the console most of the armstrong values returning it as 'This is not an armstrong number'

Comment: I tried your `armstrongNumber` function  with these values: 0, 1, 153, 370, 371, 407, and it seems to work properly
(it logs 'This is an armstrong number'). Also, I cannot see where you used a `while` loop.

Comment: yes, it works properly. I didn't used while loop over here because previously when I used while loop code, it got messier. So I removed while loop and given the clean code to better understanding. MY BASIC QUESTION is how to include while loop or for loop without giving me any errors